# Printing ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am writing a computer stock program which allow user to define and display only one sort of  computers  from an array. At the moment one computer  from an array  (e.i. first from an array) is printed but it doesn't all list of particular model.

```
model = Console.askString("A or B ? ");
item = mlist.find(model);
if (item == null)
    System.out.println("Cannot find " + model);
else
     item.print("Laptop details...");
break;
```

Comment: What's `mlist`? Does `find` return all matches, or just the first?

Comment: What is `item`? Please provide more relevant parts.

Comment: Can you post the output you're getting, and the output you expect?

Comment: Please provide more details for this question.

Add full source code of class.

Comment: what are you `break`ing? a loop? a switch? btw the break is **always** executed no matter if item is `null` or not.

Answer (score 2):

> At the moment one computer from an array (e.i.first from an array) is printed but it doesn't all list of particular model.

This is because of the break keyword. If your code snipplet was taken from a loop, the `break` will be executed after the if statement and will then break out of the loop and the whole array will not be printed. This will cause the behaviour that you've described, "first from array is printed"

```
model = Console.askString("A or B ? ");
item = mlist.find(model);
if (item == null)
    System.out.println("Cannot find " + model);
else
     item.print("Laptop details...");
break; // remove this
```

Comment: that would require for ```mlist.find(model);``` to find the first in the first loop, the second in the second and so forth... that would be... um ... unusual. But since the OP does not provide more details your solution *could* be correct. Who knows...

Answer (score 1):

In case that the `mlist.find(model)` has a signature like this:

```
List<Computer> find(String filter);
```

and that it indeed returns with a `List` you should rename `item` to `items` and then you can loop over these with

```
for (Computer computer : items){
  computer.print("Laptop details...");
}
```

That is of course only if your Computer class has a `print(String str)` method, but since you get already some printed output I assume this works.